# Getting NameError for class variable while accessing it in methods of another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

Actually I wanted to create one instance of Class 'car' and wanted to use that Object within methods of a different class. As 'carObj' is a Class variable of class 'fourWheeler', we can define just before all methods and we can use. This is the understanding I got after going through few tutorials. But why here I am getting this error. I just wanted to understand. Any suggestions/advice will help me a lot.

```
class car:
    def __init__(self,name, mileage):
        self.__name = name
        self.__mileage = mileage

    def SpeedDetails(self):
        print("Top Speed : 140")
        print("Avg speed : 80")

class fourWheeler:
    carObj = car('Honda', 20)
    def Vehicletype():
        print(carObj)

    def VehicleSpeed():
        carObj.SpeedDetails()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    vehicle = fourWheeler
    vehicle.Vehicletype()
    vehicle.VehicleSpeed()
```

The error I got after running the script:

```
ssh://root@kick-bgl-caas6.cisco.com:41114/kick/bin/python -u /tmp/pycharm_project_977/Test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_977/Test.py", line 20, in <module>
    vehicle.Vehicletype()
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_977/Test.py", line 13, in Vehicletype
    print(carObj)
**NameError: name 'carObj' is not defined**
```

Comment: Read up on [Python Classes and Objects, Section "The self"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-classes-and-objects/)

Answer (score 0):

Added your mistakes as comments

```
class car:
    def __init__(self,name, mileage):
        self.__name = name
        self.__mileage = mileage

    def SpeedDetails(self):
        print("Top Speed : 140")
        print("Avg speed : 80")

class fourWheeler:
    carObj = car('Honda', 20)
    def Vehicletype(self): #missed self here
        print(self.carObj)

    def VehicleSpeed(self): #missed self here
        self.carObj.SpeedDetails()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    vehicle = fourWheeler() # use constructor
    vehicle.Vehicletype()
    vehicle.VehicleSpeed()
```

Comment: Thanks Kris. It worked. But adding 'self' makes it a instance variable right. Please clarify me.

Comment: Also just in case, constructor call is not there. Then how can we access 'carObj'. Because in my project, 'fourWheeler' doesn't called with any argument(zero arg). This scenario how can I justify.

Comment: Any variables you create with self inside constructor becomes the instance. Other variables are class variables, which you can access with self or class-name.